# 100% height div and overflow:auto

Tags: css

I have got a vertical menu on the left side of the screen, and i want to take 100% height of the resolution, but if the div(of the menu) needs more, i want to appear scroll.
My question: I have got one div with height:100% and overflow auto.
I need have the scroll only on that div, but this div must be 100% of the resolution of the screen. Now if i put like this, the scroll takes all the page, but if i put fixed height to the div it works correctly. But i need to be 100% height. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

<strike>http://cssdesk.com/yxShB</strike> <strike>http://gearsdigital.com/sandbox/</strike> http://jsfiddle.net/WB4Qc/

Successfully tested in:

OSX

- FF 3.6
- Safari 4 + 5
- Chrome 47.0

WIN7

- IE 7
- IE 8
- FF 3.5

See my example above. The code works fine... Try to resize the window. You'll see once the bottom of the browser reaches the last list element an scrollbar appears on the menu div.

Html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    * {margin:0;padding:0;}
    html, body{
        height:100%;
        background:#eee;
    }
    #menu {
        background:#ccc;
        width:220px;
        height:100%;
    }
    #menu ul {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Comment: In IE7, a grayed out scrollbar appears on the right. It's not clear to me why this is upsetting - it's a vertical scrollbar, not a horizontal one.  This same scrollbar also appears in IE6, but again, it seems to work,  although I didn't do enough testing to ensure that it wouldn't start doing something weird when there was more content in it.

Comment: The grayed out scrollbars in IE7/6 are imho native and Browser/OS specific. It has nothing to do with my CSS... :)

Comment: As he said, those scrollbars are there by default.

Comment: You can't get rid of grayed out scrollbars in Firefox. It's a browser issue.

Comment: going to award you the bounty, unfortunately this question wasnt the question i had, i misread it, i already solved the issue but not in the way i wanted to, maybe if i have time i will repost it and send you a message : )

Comment: link broken, please fix.

Comment: I added the html and css to persist the relevant information right within the post. But as you said please i made a fiddle for you ;) See updated answer...

Answer (score 3):

I know of 2 common solutions to this:

1) Use JavaScript to determine the height of the viewport and explicitly set the height of the element to the same (e.g. something along the lines of `yourMenuDivElement.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;`. You'd also have to make sure to capture the window resize event to reset the height of the menu if the window height changes.

2) The much simpler CSS-only solution is to set the height of the `html` and `body` elements to both be 100%. I believe this generally works OK, though you may have other things on your page that could be negatively affected by setting the document height to 100% perhaps - but it's definitely worth trying it. CSS would be something like:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menu {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answers.
the second answer doesnt work form me... i have tried and i get the scroll for all the page. But the firt solution could be posible...
I am going to try it.
Thank you, really thank you for the answer and for your time

Answer (score 3):

There is a farily simple answer to this, using height: 100% on both the HTML and body selectors in CSS, you can effectively tell the menu to be 100% of the height, but scroll when it needs to.

I have made an example for you here at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/WY6zR/). (resize the Result window to see the effect)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I've completed gearsdigital response with a "content" div for the content of the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guillaume/NnW5r/11/show/

code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Guillaume/NnW5r/11/

Resize the window and scroll the page to see if it fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Works everywhere

JS

```
function overflowFillHeight(el,listener){
    var sumH = 0;
    if(el){
       var parEls = el.parentNode.childNodes;
       var style = null;
       if(parEls.length > 1){
           for(var j = 0; j < parEls.length; j++){
              if(parEls[j].nodeType != 3){
                 if(parEls[j] != el ){

                    sumH += parEls[j].clientHeight;

                    if(typeof window.getComputedStyle(parEls[j]) != 'undefined'){
                       style = window.getComputedStyle(parEls[j]);
                    }else if(typeof parEls[j].currentStyle != 'undefined'){
                       style = parEls[j].currentStyle;
                    };

                    if(style){
                       sumH += parseInt(style.marginTop);
                       sumH += parseInt(style.marginBottom);
                       sumH += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth);
                       sumH += parseInt(style.borderBottomWidth);
                    };

                 };
              };
           };
       };

       style = null;
       if(typeof window.getComputedStyle(el) != 'undefined'){
          style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
       }else if(typeof el.currentStyle != 'undefined'){
          style = el.currentStyle;
       };

       if(style){
          sumH += parseInt(style.marginTop);
          sumH += parseInt(style.marginBottom);
          sumH += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth);
          sumH += parseInt(style.borderBottomWidth);
       };

       el.style.height = (el.parentNode.clientHeight - sumH)+'px';

       if(!listener){
          window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
             overflowFillHeight(el,true);
          },false);
       };
    };
};
```

example

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
    function overflowFillHeight(el,listener){
        var sumH = 0;
        if(el){
           var parEls = el.parentNode.childNodes;
           var style = null;
           if(parEls.length > 1){
               for(var j = 0; j < parEls.length; j++){
                  if(parEls[j].nodeType != 3){
                     if(parEls[j] != el ){

                        sumH += parEls[j].clientHeight;

                        if(typeof window.getComputedStyle(parEls[j]) != 'undefined'){
                           style = window.getComputedStyle(parEls[j]);
                        }else if(typeof parEls[j].currentStyle != 'undefined'){
                           style = parEls[j].currentStyle;
                        };

                        if(style){
                           sumH += parseInt(style.marginTop);
                           sumH += parseInt(style.marginBottom);
                           sumH += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth);
                           sumH += parseInt(style.borderBottomWidth);
                        };

                     };
                  };
               };
           };

           style = null;
           if(typeof window.getComputedStyle(el) != 'undefined'){
              style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
           }else if(typeof el.currentStyle != 'undefined'){
              style = el.currentStyle;
           };

           if(style){
              sumH += parseInt(style.marginTop);
              sumH += parseInt(style.marginBottom);
              sumH += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth);
              sumH += parseInt(style.borderBottomWidth);
           };

           el.style.height = (el.parentNode.clientHeight - sumH)+'px';

           if(!listener){
              window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
                 overflowFillHeight(el,true);
              },false);
           };
        };
    };
    </script>
    <style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    html,body{
        height:100%;
    }
    .g1{
        margin-bottom:34px;
        border:20px double #CCFF00;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div style="height:100%; background:#F00;">
    <div class="g1" style="height:37px; background:#00F;">1</div>
    <div id="qqq" class="g1" style="background:#39F; overflow:auto; height:300px;">
       <div style="height:1000px;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px; background:#060;">3</div>
    </div>
    <script>
       overflowFillHeight(document.getElementById('qqq'));
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```