# Nested div will not scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to take a nested div and make it scrollable but I am having some difficulty. The problem child is the div with the class named "items".

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div>I want the div below to scroll</div>
      <div class="items">
        <div>item</div>       
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.items {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}


.header {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Codepen Link:
https://codepen.io/allencoded/pen/abdmwmQ?editors=1100

I am not sure what is going on. I have set the overflow on items to be `scroll`, I figured that would do the trick but appears I am wrong. Is there a way to make the .items scroll like this? If not why?

Comment: Might be a [duplicate of this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387162/100-height-div-and-overflowauto/4892718)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set 100% at your height property from `.items` class, your `<div>` tag will expand until all nested items are shown. To enable your scroll , the height of the `<div>` with class `.items` must be lower to what it would have if your div expanded to accommodate all nested tags.

Try to set your height property lower than 100% or set in pixels (100px, for instance).

Comment: I see. So I am guessing in order to just have the div end at the bottom of the page I will need to do some kind of calculation via JS?

Comment: That is a good question.  I never tried this before, but I think this thread below can help you achieve what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793194/how-to-extend-divs-height-till-the-footer-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 2):

reduce the height of the items class as 100% will display all contents.